# slice an array on left of a given point

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
$array = array (
  0 => '730',
  1 => '724',
  2 => '720',
  3 => '530',
  4 => '56',
  5 => '76',
  6 => '528',
  7 => '394',
  8 => '390',
  9 => '388',
)
```

I have a given point in the array, say `$a = 5`, which translates to the value `56`

Now, I need to get the two values on both sides of this given point. For the values on the right of `$a`, I use the following

```
    $keys = array_slice( $array, $a, $x_from_current );
```

which gives me correctly the values `76` and `528`

I cannot however get the 2 values on the left, which in this case is `720` and `530`. I cannot get the offset to work correctly

Any idea on how to get these two values on the left, and am I even using the correct function here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up doing the following, which suites my needs perfectly

- Use `array_reverse` to reverse the array
- Next, recalculate the new position of `$a`
- Use `array_slice` as normal

Here is the end code:

```
$array = array (
  0 => '730',
  1 => '724',
  2 => '720',
  3 => '530',
  4 => '56',
  5 => '76',
  6 => '528',
  7 => '394',
  8 => '390',
  9 => '388',
);

$a = 5;
$reverse_position   = count( $array ) - ( $a );
$array_reverse      = array_reverse( $array );
$sliced_reverse     = array_slice( $array_reverse, $reverse_position + 1, 2 );

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($sliced_reverse);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
array_slice($array, $a - 3, 2)
```

Comment: I was first. But I support low reps :-)

Comment: It works, but the problem is, say `$a` is `2`, it returns the last value which is `388`

Answer (score 2):

```
$keys = array_slice($array, $a-3, 2);
var_dump($keys);
```

[returns](http://3v4l.org/I1DRC)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "720"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "530"
}
```

Comment: It works, but the problem is, say `$a` is `2`, it returns the last value which is `388`